# What is the correct syntax for using "Begins With" when setting a Filename Pattern in an import automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

I am new to Salesforce and I am trying to setup an import automation. I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax when using the "Begins with" option in the filename pattern.

The docs say you can use it but do not provide an example. I find a few other related questions but all the answers just point to the docs, which don't help me.

Can someone provide an example of how to use the "Begins with" option when setting the Filename pattern?

I am after something like:    BEGINS WITH "TEST02" in order to detect all filenames that begin with TEST02 followed by any number of other characters.

I understand the logic. What I am having trouble with is the syntax.

[image: Filename Pattern Image]

I am having trouble with the proper syntax of the pattern. I have tried a number of different variations but it won't recognize any of them as valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you clicked the **i** next to *File naming pattern*? It indeed works exactly like you described. Setting the **Begins with:** setting to *TEST02* will “catch” any file that begins with *TEST02* regardless of what comes later in the file name:

[image]

In your example, you should set the filter on the import trigger, and the field should only contain *TEST02* and not “Begins with TEST02”
Examples:

- TEST02_January.csv : works
- TEST02.csv : works
- JANUARY_TEST02.csv : will not be fetched

When you set up the File Import Activity itself, you should use: `%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` - It automatically takes the file name of the file which originally triggered the automation. Mind you, that in some cases you will need to use `%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv` as the file arriving to the FTP has a *.part* suffix, until it has finished uploading from the external source. If you would use `%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` the import will fail, as it will be looking for *TEST02.csv.part*

You can find additional best practices for importing files [on this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscriber_import_file_requirements.htm&type=5). Reference for file name patterns [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_filename_patterns_reference.htm&type=5). And my favourite: [Substitution Strings Example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5).

It is not possible to use any other wildcards than `%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%` so your example of 'TEST02*' is unfortunately not doable in the File Import activity itself.

Comment: If I click on the "i" all I get is a help bubble. I don't have the option you show above (Begins with dropdown). If I click on the "File Naming Pattern" link the only Insert option that appears is for DateTime.

Comment: @DMK there is a link to documentation in the bubble. You will need to combine the file drop trigger with your file import activity, to be able to define a file name pattern with “begins with” as a condition, as I describe